# Not able to fit the Menu width as same as the containers width using material-ui (mui-v5) and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I was trying to create a **Menu** that had to be the same width as the `Button`. But somehow the width for the `Menu` is not getting set as intended. Just for trial purposes I also tried placing the whole menu in a `Grid` Item container and tried to fit it inside. But even that didn't work.
I have tried giving `absolute` styling but still, that didn't work. It used to make it either very huge or very small.

Here is a code to play with. I have recreated the same issue that I am facing and is open to editing.

**[CustomButton Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-trial-uw1o5?file=/src/App.js)**

This project has one single file that has all the essential code in it. i.e: `ButtonCustom.js`.
Please go through it and please give me a solution for the same. I want to keep it responsive that is why I have used `Grid` in the project.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you already save the `Button` native html element in state (it is the `anchorEl`), you can define the width of the menu list as the width of the button.

It can be done with just one line of code:

```
    <Menu
      // other props here
      MenuListProps={{
         "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
         sx: { width: anchorEl && anchorEl.offsetWidth } // <-- The line that does all
      }}
    >
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!